# Run different function in different threads/task in R

Tags: r, multithreading, thread-safety, task

Does R have any mechanism to run different calculation in different threads (Windows-like mechanism of threads/tasks)? Let's

```
func1 <- function(x) { return (x^2); }
func2 <- function(y) { return (y^3); }
```

I need to execute something like this (imagine code):

```
thread1 <- thread_run(func1);
thread2 <- thread_run(func2);
```

with same mechanism of synchronization, like:

```
wait(thread1);
wait(thread2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the future package

```
install.packages(future)
library(future)
```

And then just use your code and just change the assigment to

```
thread1 %<-% thread_run(func1);
thread2 %<-% thread_run(func2);
```

Here more to read: http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-future-for-r-slides-from-user-2016/

Comment: Very, very interesting! Thank you!